# Is there any way I can have my own custom shortcuts for categories in Outlook 2007?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2007

It seems like I only can choose from:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>

Is there any way I can assign my own shortcut keys (outside of this range) to categorizing email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a macro, then add it to the menu and assign that menu item a shortcut key.

Comment: how do you write a macro in outlook?

Comment: On the Tools menu, point to Macro, and then click Macros.

In the Macro Name box, type the name that you want for the macro (without spaces), and then click Create. This starts the Visual Basic Editor and automatically creates a subroutine for you.

Then you can use the customize menu to create new items linked to those subroutines, and you can use & to create shortcuts (F&oobar will create a item that can be accessed by Alt-o)